# Network manager show eth0 connection but no interenet access

Tags: linux, network-interface, networkmanager, ethernet

I tried `ping www.google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` and access the web browser manually, resulting in "server couldn't connect".

I have 3 connections via eth0, wlan0 and wlan1(through USB) , eth0 **doesn't** have internet access and when I activate wlan0 or wlan1 with eth0 I dont have internet access, but when I activate **only wlan0 or wlan1** I **do**, when I activate **eth0 alone**, I **dont** have internet access, so maybe something in eth0 configurations?

I do get an IP for eth0:

[image: ipconnection]

[image: routing]

I tried disabling Wi-Fi cause i've read somewhere that wlan0/1 could be the default access and avoiding internet connection from eth0,but it didn't work also.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

My `etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you **use** NetworkManager, why don't you simply let NetworkManager handle all connections.

In other words, remove

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

From your `/etc/network/interfaces`, and change to:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

In your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Official documentation **[here](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager)**.

Comment: Tried, and restarted network manager, the problem remains.
I read the documentation, and followed the instructions, didnt help too.
When using ethernet and wireless together, no internet access, when using only ethernet no internet access, only wireless has internet access. 
Tried ping with only ethernet  -> no reponse , same as ethernet with wireless no response from ping 8.8.8.8 .
Any other suggestions that may help?
I have changed my question accordingly.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Not sure if you have been able to solve it?

Comment: @maulinglawns I know this is and old post but shouldn't it be `managed=true`?